# Linefitting to 6 dimensional points

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I would like to find a line best-fitting an arbitrary set of input points in 6 dimensions. Is there an efficient algorithm to accomplish this. Does the usual linear least square approach work here?

Comment: sure, least squares would do just fine in any integral number of dimensions

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.... so essentially every dimension is treated independently?